# Elastic search query to find Total Login User count

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5

1. Total Distinct Login User Cumulative count - Column ( User ID)
2. Total Accounts searched User Cumulative count (Account ID)

I Tried Below queries but not getting the Count

GET /Logstach/_Search_Tracking/_count?q=user:userId

GET /Logstach/_Search_Tracking/_count?q=user:AccountId

Below output got

{
"count" : 0,
"_shards" : {
"total" : 3,
"successful" : 3,
"skipped" : 0,
"failed" : 0
}
}

Below is the Index Mapping details

```
        "_index" : "ABC",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "08c28b9c-dd07-47c0-8243-3afc4fe89c08",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "user" : {
            "userId" : "A123",
            "userCategory" : "Outside",
            "accountId" : "ABC58"
          },
```

Comment: do you want to get the count of unique number of `userId` ?

Comment: Yes I need the Count of Unique number of User ID

Answer (score 0):

You need to query like this: `...?q=user.userId:A123` and `...?q=user.accountId:ABC58` because both fields are located within the `user` object

```
GET /Logstach/_Search_Tracking/_count?q=user.userId:A123
                                          ^
                                          |
                                       add this

GET /Logstach/_Search_Tracking/_count?q=user.accountId:ABC58
                                          ^
                                          |
                                       add this
```

Now if you want the distinct number of users that have logged in, yu need to use the `cardinality` aggregation

```
GET /Logstach/_Search_Tracking/_search
{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "distinct_loggedin": {
            "cardinality": {
                "field": "user.userId"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Same for the total number of accounts searched:

```
GET /Logstach/_Search_Tracking/_search
{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "total_accounts": {
            "cardinality": {
                "field": "user.accountId"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting the following error //////type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason" : "Text fields are not optimised for operations that require per-document field data like aggregations and sorting, so these operations are disabled by default. Please use a keyword field instead. Alternatively, set fielddata=true on [user.userId] in order to load field data by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can use significant memory."

Comment: Thanks it is working fine but For Unique Total User id and Total Account id count is coming same.

Comment: Actually One user id searched 5 times so it should see 1 count right? In the Database Total count itself 184 but when we split to Unique Total User id and Total Account id count is coming same as 184

Comment: Can you update your question with the response you get please?

Comment: This is the response I am getting for the bothe Questions{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 3,
    "successful" : 3,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 189,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "total_accounts" : {
      "value" : 0
    }
  }
}

Comment: My Requirement is I Have total records count is 184 out of which i need to split How many Unique Total user searched??? and How many total Account id searched.??

Comment: Can you **update your question** with the mapping of your index please?

Comment: Ok, the problem is that `user.userId` and `user.accountId` are mapped as text. You need to map them as `keyword` instead and then the above queries will work. Since that's only 184 documents, it's easy for you to rebuild the index, I reckon.